# Angular - Overwrite (only) one property of the environment

Tags: angular, environment-variables, development-environment

I have an Angular application and I have created different environmet for different clients:

```
{
name: client1,
address: client 1 address,
... a lot of variables
variableToChange: thisWantModify
}
```

and everything works fine for me when I do

```
ng serve --configuration = client1
```

or

```
ng build --configuration = client1
```

The variables works ok.

The problem I have is that I want to change the value of that (and only that) variable (ToChange variable) when I do

```
ng build --configuration = client1
```

I know that one solution would be to duplicate the environment and use

```
ng build --configuration = client1build
```

but I have many clients and it would double the amount of environment files.

Is possible to do it in other way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to have placeholders in your environment.ts file for the properties that might require override within a environment. Then create a custom script which will replace that placeholder with appropriate value and then invoke ng build.